# Each pod has its own Hazelcast iList

Tags: java, kubernetes, hazelcast

I configured in the `hazelcast.xml` file of my microservice a list like following

```xml
<list name="listA">
    <statistics-enabled>false</statistics-enabled>
    <backup-copy>1</backup-copy>
<list>
```

When I deployed the microservice on k8s cluster with replicas=2, I was expecting that the values of `listA` are shared to both pods, meaning that when `pod-0` add an entry to `listA` that entry will be visible for `pod-1`. But I found that each pod has its own separate instance and I am not sure why, any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Or should I use Hazelcast's `IMap` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your pods formed a cluster ?

Do you get a message in the logs such as:

```
Members {size:2, ver:2} [
    Member [12.34.56.001]:5701 - 7ee6659e-620c-4db6-b348-8769000c2b0a
    Member [12.34.56.002]:5701 - 41238cc4-ef9a-4d50-94a7-a8fab67f43de this
]
```

If you see `size:2` it's a cluster of two pods. If it's a cluster of two pods, your `listA` should be accessible from both.

If you have `replicas==2` then you'll get two pods, but if they can't find each other they'll form two clusters of one pod rather than one cluster of two pods.

You need to check the discovery section for Kubernetes. See [here](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/deploy/configuring-kubernetes).
The easiest way is to turn off multicast, turn on Kubernetes, use the default namespace and a service name. Once you have that running you can expand to
different namespaces, roles, operators, helm charts, etc.

[This guide](https://guides.hazelcast.org/kubernetes/) might help also.